# How to handle environment-specific settings in your rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Currently, the rails environment for my local machine development, i am getting reset password url like this 'localhost:3001/reset_password/aBRINDss'.
i am getting localhost:3001 because i am using development env.

currently in mailer i am using the environment like this

```
@reset_password_email = Settings.DEVELOPMENT_HOST_URL + '/users/reset_password/' + user.reset_password_token
```

is there any way in which i don't have to mention different HOST_URL in application.yml for each env and it takes automatically host url according to it's current environment. and i can use it here direct in `@reset_password_email = Settings.DEVELOPMENT_HOST_URL + '/users/reset_password/' + user.reset_password_token`
in place of ***Settings.DEVELOPMENT_HOST_URL***

Comment: @dbugger no , want to implement it in the credential.yml

Answer (score 1):

You can specify blocks for specific environments like this

```yaml
production:
  aws:
    access_key_id: 123
    secret_access_key: 345
```

Take a look here for more info: https://blog.engineyard.com/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2